# Carthage Access Token

Tags: ios, git, carthage

I use Carthage as a dependency manager for my iOS apps.

After using 'carthage update --platform iOS' got an email from github saying 'you used a password to access an endpoint through the GitHub API using org.carthage.CarthageKit/0.34.0' and that basic authentication is deprecated. What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix this, in your CLI/Terminal, you need to replace your cached GitHub password with a GitHub personal access token.

On Mac, if you are using credential-osxkeychain credential helper, your credentials are stored in the keychain.

See these instructions: [Updating credentials from the OS X Keychain](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain)

I had to delete both the `github.com` and `gcm4ml:git:https://github.com` stored passwords in the keychain.

To create the personal access token, see these instructions: [Creating a personal access token for the command line](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line)

Next time git asks for you password, use the personal access token.